# Nodejs AWS S3 deleteObject() If you put in the missing key, you'll find it DeleteMarker true

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

If you send it with the right key, it will be deleted. I thought it was good because DeleteMarker got true, but if you send it with a key that is not in S3, DeleteMarker true comes out. What should we do with the validation?

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId:awsConfig.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: awsConfig.secretAccessKey,
    region: awsConfig.region,
});


(async function () {
    const params = {
        Bucket: awsConfig.bucket,
        Key: '17f316af9b011f08b68538a8ac76b73f.jpg',
    };
    const deleteS3Data = await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();

    if(deleteS3Data.DeleteMarker !== true){
       throw new Error("I don't have the key.");
    }else{
          return deleteS3Data;

    }
 
    
    
}())


// deleteS3Data Whatever comes out true
```